# xelement get same children nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I try get same children nodes value

I want to get children regularly

how to which the child belongs this value

```
XElement element = XElement.Load(filedialog.FileName);

var items = (from el in element.Descendants("property")
select new 
{
   values = el.Attribute("type").Value
}
.ToList();
gridControl.DataSource = items;
```

sample xml:

```
<node>
<properties>
  <property type="application">denedim try1</property>
  <property type="direction">in1</property>
  <property type="to">verici verrrrrrr1</property>
  <property type="text_body">patladi yaw1</property>
  <property type="time" year="2013"</property>
  <property type="from_id">6066256731</property>
  <property type="to_id">6700378141</property>
  <property type="status">FREE1</property>
  <property type="uid">1501</property>
  <property type="storage">USB1</property>
</properties>
</node>

<node>
<properties>
  <property type="application">denedim try</property>
  <property type="direction">in</property>
  <property type="to">verici verrrrrrr</property>
  <property type="text_body">patladi yaw</property>
  <property type="time" year="2013"</property>
  <property type="from_id">606625673</property>
  <property type="to_id">670037814</property>
  <property type="status">FREE</property>
  <property type="uid">150</property>
  <property type="storage">USB</property>
</properties>
</node>
```

Comment: didnt get you,please elaborate

Comment: Is there an error? Do you get different results as expected?

Comment: please include your expected output, and the output you get currently

Comment: no there isnt an error but is not regularly result.  result of which the child

Comment: What do you Want actually?

Comment: I think he wants something like `//property[@type="..."]/text()` but I can't express than in LINQ :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, you missed a ')'. Next, you try to load an xml doc in an XElement ?

You can try it :

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filedialog.FileName);

foreach (XElement elem in doc.Descendants("property"))
{
list.add(elem.Attribute("type").Value);
}
gridControl.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: XElement has a [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298435(v=vs.110).aspx) method to load from a file.  There isn't anything wrong about that.

Comment: yes this code is fine I cant explain my problem. acctuly I want get element like groups. that value which elements  in data groups

Comment: I don't really understand... You want a list of group of XElement ?
Or you want to group each element by their attributes ? (example
`Dictionnary<string, List<string>> dico = new Dictionnary<string, XElement>();
foreach (XElement elem in doc.Descendants("property"))
{
if (dico[elem.attribute("type").value] == null)
   dico[elem.attribute("type").value] = new List<string>();
dico[elem.attribute("type").value].add(elem.value);`
}

Answer (score 0):

element is loaded and contains the `<node>` XElement.  The only descendent of `<node>` is `<properties>`.  I think you want this instead:

```
var items = (from el in element.Element("properties").Descendants("property")
    select new
    {
        values = el.Attribute("type").Value
    }).ToList();
```